# Python: Parse/Split by Ignoring first space from right

Tags: python, parsing, split

I am having trouble parsing String2, by a space. Thoughts?

```
String1 = "THIS IS STRING1 18-23-80-18"

String2 = "THIS IS STRING2 7-A-4, 4-93-P"

Split1 = String1.rsplit(" ",2)

Output1 = "18-23-80-18" #This Works fine

Split2 = String2.????? # Not sure what to do here 

Output2 = "7-A-4, 4-93-P" #How do I Ignore the first space from the right?
```

Clarification:

The * represents the space I am trying to ignore and the % represents the space I want to find.

```
"%7-A-4,*4-93-P"
```

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know that you want to keep the `*` space and not the `%` space? What are you looking for, when you look at the string and determine (as a human, not a program) where to split it?

Comment: The * represents a space that is always contained in the string, but it's to be ignored.

Comment: What I mean is: when you see `"THIS IS STRING2 7-A-4, 4-93-P"`, you say you want to split it as `("THIS IS STRING2", "7-A-4, 4-93-P")`. But why is it not, for example, `("THIS IS", "STRING2 7-A-4, 4-93-P")`? What is **special** about the space that you want to use for splitting? How do you **know** that's the space you want to split on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to split the string:

```
>>> import re
>>> string2 = "THIS IS STRING2 7-A-4, 4-93-P"
>>> re.split(r'[^,]\s+', string2)[-1]
'7-A-4, 4-93-P'
```

Comment: I choose this answer because it may not always be the third space from the left.

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in splitting the string on the third left space and ignoring all others on the right then after:

```
>>> String2 = "THIS IS STRING2 7-A-4, 4-93-P"
>>> String2.split(" ", 3)[3]
'7-A-4, 4-93-P'
```

A general approach would be to split on spaces on the whole string and pick only from the range you want. Then join that range using a space.

```
" ".join(string.split()[1:3])
```